# vscode: Unable to connect to remote machine vai Remote-SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get the below error while trying to connect to one of the remote machines, I was able to login to a different remote machine:

```
[19:26:24.304] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+devde", attempt 1
[19:26:24.304] SSH Resolver called for host: devde
[19:26:24.304] Setting up SSH remote "devde"
[19:26:24.352] Using commit id "6ab598523be7a800d7f3eb4d92d7ab9a66069390" and quality "stable" for server
[19:26:24.355] Testing ssh with ssh -V
[19:26:24.377] ssh exited with code: 0
[19:26:24.377] Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
[19:26:24.383] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 51911 -o ConnectTimeout=15 devde bash
[19:26:24.384] Install and start server if needed
[19:26:29.111] > bash: bash: command not found
[19:26:29.112] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[19:26:29.370] "install" terminal command done
[19:26:29.370] Install terminal quit with output: bash: bash: command not found
[19:26:29.370] Received install output: bash: bash: command not found
[19:26:29.371] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[19:26:29.372] Resolver error: 
[19:26:29.375] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"UnparsableOutput","askedPw":"0","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"1"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
[19:26:29.377] ------
```

I have tried tinkering with terminal related settings in `vscode`, but nothing helped, also I have seen few bug-files in github but they were not helpful.

I also deleted the .vscode-server folder from remote, did not help.

Also tried `Remote-SSH: Kill vscode server on host` command, did not help.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this has something to do with

```
[19:26:29.370] Install terminal quit with output: bash: bash: command not found
[19:26:29.370] Received install output: bash: bash: command not found
```

looks like the remote session doesnt seem to be able to start bash.
can you check whats listed in your ssh config file on your local machine

Comment: I highly doubt it is because of the local config because I am able to open a remote session on a different remote machine. I am finding it hard what is different in the 2 remote machines.